# The connection was not closed

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

This is doing my head in. I have tried `try` and `catch` with `finally` and other things but this error keeps coming back. Please some one help.
My c# code:

```
 void show()
    {
       string str = "SELECT PID, Pname, Gender, ContactNum, Category, Department, Ward, AdmitDate, DischargeDate, NumOfDays, CostOfTest, NumOfDocsVisited, DocFee, BedCost, TotalCost, GrandTotal FROM Patient";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adp.Fill(dt);
            GridView1.DataBind();
                con.Close();
    }
```

error is:

> The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>   Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The connection
>   was not closed. The connection's current state is open.

Source Error:

```
Line 50:            string str = "SELECT PID, Pname, Gender, ContactNum, Category, Department, Ward, AdmitDate, DischargeDate, NumOfDays, CostOfTest, NumOfDocsVisited, DocFee, BedCost, TotalCost, GrandTotal FROM Patient";
Line 51:             cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
Line 52:                 con.Open();
Line 53:                 SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
Line 54:                 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
```

Stack Trace:

```
[InvalidOperationException: The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.]
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +14
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +94
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +110
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
SMC.Billing.show() in e:\VS2013 projects\SMC\SMC\Billing.aspx.cs:52
SMC.Billing.Button3_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in e:\VS2013 projects\SMC\SMC\Billing.aspx.cs:97
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9628722
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

Comment: Use the `using` clause to insure your connections are disposed of and closed properly should clear this up.

Comment: how and where can i use that?

Comment: where in your code are you using `con` it's obvious that you are using a global connection and why not just add the following or check for the following State of the `con` just put `con.Close()` before calling the Open method.. but that's a poor way.. I would do a conditional check.. and to really be safe..wrap all of your sql objects around a `using(){}` this will ensure auto disposing of the objects and underlying object etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your connection in a `using` block.  This guarantees it always gets closed.

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
  connection.Open();
  //Do stuff with the connection
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like it is trying to tell you that you are trying to open an already open connection.

You might try (on line 52)

```
if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed) con.Open;
```

Comment: i have already tried that